# NavigationBar titleview image move to another image with animation while scrolling

Tags: ios, swift

#### Green Image Place to Orange image exact match (x, y, width, height)

I try to move navigation bar titleView image to another image (Orange Image) with animation while user scrolling table view and when scroll up and down the put image to original place.

**Sample Code**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

    imgViewSmall = UIImageView.init(frame: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 44, height: 44))
    imgViewSmall.backgroundColor = .green
    self.navigationItem.titleView = imgViewSmall
    imgView.backgroundColor = .orange

    animator.pauseAnimation()
    
    animator.addAnimations {
        var smallSize = self.imgViewSmall.frame
        let bigSize = self.imgView.frame

        smallSize.size.width = bigSize.width
        smallSize.size.height = bigSize.height

        self.imgViewSmall.center = bigImageCoordinate
    }
}
```

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        
        let minHeight:CGFloat = 0.0
        let maxHeight:CGFloat = 170.0
        
        factor = ((scrollView.contentOffset.y - minHeight)) / (maxHeight - minHeight)
        
        // update the new position acquired
        self.lastContentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y
        
        if factor == 0 {
            //animator.stopAnimation(false)
        }
        else if factor == 1 {
            //animator.stopAnimation(false)
        }
        else {
            //animator.startAnimation()
            animator.fractionComplete = factor
        }
        
        self.navigationItem.titleView?.setNeedsDisplay()
        print("factor \(factor ?? 0)")
    }
```

[image]